# Como faço para sugerir um sinônimo?

Tags: suporte

Notei que existem três tags com o mesmo propósito:

[tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela) : Poderia ser qualquer tipo de tabela, mas segundo o Wiki trata-se de um elemento HTML.
[table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) : Elemento HTML.
[html-table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table) : Também um elemento HTML.

Como faço para sugerir que as três torne-se sinônimos?
Ou então, que das três existentes sejam removidas duas e as perguntas sejam "migradas" para uma tag única?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se não tem reputação para fazer isto na página da *tag*, pode pedir aqui ou sinalizar para um moderador se for algo eventual.

Precisa ver como estas *tags* realmente estão sendo usadas. O ideal seria dar uma organizada antes. Na [tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela) tem perguntas sobre banco de dados.

Comment: Posso considerar essa pergunta um pedido para unificar as três tags? Parece que a tag [tag:tabela] tinha como propósito servir para perguntas sobre banco de dados, acho que foi aquele Wiki que confundiu as coisas. Falo isso porque é mais fácil relacionar [tag:table] ao elemento HTML pelo fato de ter o mesmo nome da tag `<table>`.

Comment: Acho que sim, um usuário com rep ou moderador verá. Mas tenho sérias dúvidas sobre a [tag:tabela]

Comment: Eu acho que a tag [tag:tabela] deveria ir para uma lista negra, pois o seu significado varia muito de acordo com o contexto.